# How to model relationship between different parent entities and one common child entity

Tags: java, hibernate, database-design, modeling

I'm looking for some suggestions for best practices around modeling the relationship between various entities and their documents (binaries such as PDF, TIFF etc).  The entities are standard JPA/Hibernate stored in a PostgreSQL database.  The documents themselves will be stored in MongoDb database.

The plan is to create a child entity to represent the document, which contains the id to the binary data to retrieve it as needed.  But what would the relationship be?

If I simply created one if these document entities for each parent entity then a simple one to many relationship would work, but that seems to redundant.

I could simply put a "type" column that indicates which entity the document belongs to, and then query the document table with a named query of "id = ? and type = ?".  I guess that would work, but there is something about that I'm not crazy about either - just can't put my finger on it :)  Maybe that's just fine.

Another option I have looked at (although I admit I have never used it before, and would need to study it a bit more) is to use a unidirectional one to many with join table.  However, I don't think this will work either since there is no guarantee that there wouldn't be duplicate parent keys.  I use a single sequence for all basic relation tables primary keys, which should guarantee it, but it still doesn't sound like a good idea.

Finally, I have considered whether I create an entity and then extend it for each parent entity, but I think that would have the same flaw - the theoretical existence of non-unique parent ids.

Before I make a final decision, I'd like to see what other suggestions the community might have to offer.

Thanks in advance for your ideas.

Comment: did you find an answer? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

> If I simply created one if these document entities for each parent entity then a simple one to many relationship would work, but that seems to redundant.

I'm a bit confused. If you create a document for each parent, isn't that one-to-one and not one-to-many? It sounds like you want a one-to-many relationship. In which case, you would only create a single document for all parent entities that reference it.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear.  Each parent entity has a one to many relationship to its documents.  For instance, a merchant may have a set of documents such as an application and a contract.  Then each customer would also have various documents such as an application, credit report etc.   However, if I have 12 parent entities, then I would have to define 12 child entities for the documents as well.  That's what I am trying to avoid.  I'm looking for a good way to define one document entity that I can use for all the parent entities.  Does that make sense?